# Find the reason for receiving a Google+ notification

Tags: google-plus, notifications

Is there any way to understand exactly *why* one got a particular notification about a new post in a message thread?  I can guess many possible reasons, but I'd really like to click on some meta information for a notification that describes exactly what was the trigger for the notification.  Why did the server(s) decide to send me the notification exactly?

I occasionally get what appear to be random notifications for a thread.  It contains no posts from any "person" that I recognize.  It's *possible* that I inadvertently performed some action to follow the thread.  But how can I confirm that to be the case or *not* to be the case.

Best answers would point to ways to find concrete evidence.  Next best describe effective sleuthing techniques if no concrete evidence can be unearthed without having access to data only available to a behind-the-scenes google admin (i.e., not me).

Comment: If you have no idea why you got the notification, it could be that the poster explicitly requested all the people to be notified. There are still a bunch of people in G+ that don't get how obnoxious that is, and do it whenever they post. You can block the poster and be rid of those notifcations.

Comment: Aganju, there are a number of reasons why one might get a notification.  The question is how to find out (for sure) which one is the actual reason.  In the particular that that triggered this particular question, I never participated in any way (e.g., comment) in the post, so even if the poster requested that "all the people" be notified should not include me since I had never participated in any way in the thread.  But whatever the reason, the point is - can one find data that provides the reason without having to guess.

Comment: When you post, you can request that _all the people in one or all of your circles_ get notified. That's what I meant he might have done. You have no control over him adding you to his circles, and you have no control over him using that flag - except blocking him. You can check if you are in his circles, but you cannot check if he chose to notify all his circle's members.

Comment: And I did understand your question and I know that this is not an answer, which is why I did not make it an answer. I just wanted to point out to you the most common reason for your situation.

Comment: Fair enough, Aganju.  FWIW, no one who posted to the particular thread that triggered this question has me in their circles.